# Microsoft Azure: What is generating frequent ~/Monitor/MonitorPage.aspx page requests?

Tags: azure

We have an ASP.NET web site supported by two web role instances running in VMs on Azure with the latest Azure SDK for .NET 2.5.  Suddenly we are seeing dozens of the following exceptions:

```
Error Caught in Application_Error event
SOURCE: System.Web
ERROR MESSAGE: The file '/Monitor/MonitorPage.aspx' does not exist.
STACK TRACE:   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) EVENT LOG ENTRY TYPE: Error
VERSION: MyApp, Version=10.7.5521.24961, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Error on Page: /Monitor/MonitorPage.aspx Error in URL: http://255.255.255.255/Monitor/MonitorPage.aspx
FORM: 
QUERYSTRING: 
WEB BROWSER: Unknown 0.0
USER HOST ADDRESS:  255.255.255.255
USER HOST NAME:  255.255.255.255
```

where I have intentionally obfuscated the app name and IP address.

I looked at the siteroot directories of both instances and neither of them had a `~/Monitor/MonitorPage.aspx` page.

I looked at the application event logs on both instances for errors.  The errors on one instance appeared excessive.  So, I re-imaged it.  Now the errors on both instances Application logs appear nominal, but the exceptions are still being thrown about once every 30 seconds.

The other clue is that the cloud service Monitor page in the Azure management console is blank including the last 7 days timespan.  It has never been blank before.

After reading [Configuring Diagnostics for Azure Cloud Services and Virtual Machines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn186185.aspx) for SDK 2.5, I realized that I was missing a diagnostics config file.  So I added it to the web role and redeployed.  Here is my obfuscated diagnostics.wadcfgx file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DiagnosticsConfiguration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
  <PublicConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
    <WadCfg>
      <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="4096">
        <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error" />
        <Directories scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
          <IISLogs containerName="wad-iis-logfiles" />
          <FailedRequestLogs containerName="wad-failedrequestlogs" />
        </Directories>
        <PerformanceCounters scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Available MBytes" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Web Service(_Total)\ISAPI Extension Requests/sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Web Service(_Total)\Bytes Total/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET Applications(__Total__)\Requests/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET Applications(__Total__)\Errors Total/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Queued" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Rejected" sampleRate="PT3M" />
          <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" sampleRate="PT3M" />
        </PerformanceCounters>
        <WindowsEventLog scheduledTransferPeriod="PT30M">
          <DataSource name="Application!*" />
          <DataSource name="MyAppLog!*" />
        </WindowsEventLog>
        <CrashDumps>
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="WaIISHost.exe" />
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="WaWorkerHost.exe" />
          <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="w3wp.exe" />
        </CrashDumps>
        <Logs scheduledTransferPeriod="PT30M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error" />
      </DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
    </WadCfg>
    <StorageAccount>joqs</StorageAccount>
  </PublicConfig>
  <PrivateConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
    <StorageAccount name="MyAzureStorageAccountName" key="MyAzureStorageAccountKey==" endpoint="https://core.windows.net/" />
  </PrivateConfig>
  <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
</DiagnosticsConfiguration>
```

Another clue is that I DID see a copy of the diagnostics.wadcfgx file in the F:\approot\bin directory of the web role.

Unfortunately, the exceptions didn't stop.  So, I submitted an Azure support request to Microsoft.  The support engineer verified that the unwanted page requests were being generated from an Azure IP address.  But, they haven't been able to tell me the origins of the requests.  As a stop gap measure, it was easier to create a dummy page to satisfy the requests rather than block the IP address as outlined at [Block Specific IP Addresses from Accessing a Web Role](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj154098.aspx).

Does anyone know what might be generating these frequent ~/Monitor/MonitorPage.aspx requests?

Comment: Microsoft Azure support has identified that the issue was caused by a bug in the SLB (Software Load Balancer).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure support has identified that the issue was caused by a bug in the SLB (Software Load Balancer).